# Где найти описание тегов sqlplan?

Tags: xml, sql-server

Здравствуйте. В SQL Managment Studio есть возможность выполнить запрос с выводом плана. План сохраняется в файл с расширением .sqlplan и имеет синтаксис xml. Мне надо распарсить план, но я не знаю всех тегов (то есть пишу парсер на основании того, что вижу), поэтому при открытии другого плана, может что-то пойти не так. Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: Ну, вот [тут](http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/07/showplan/), например, есть соответствующие XSD-файлы для разных версий сервера (правда, почему-то без 2014).

Comment: Спасибо, добрый человек )

Comment: @Yaant оформите как полноценный ответ? Ответы в комментариях - зло. Кстати, 2014 там есть - current version

Comment: @PashaPash Оформил. Изначально удовольствовался комментарием, ибо не был уверен, что автору вопросу вопроса будет достаточно XSD-схем. Да, насчет current version сразу не сообразил. Но зато нету 2008 R2. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот [тут](http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/07/showplan/) есть соответствующие XSD-файлы для разных версий сервера, начиная с 2005. Ссылку туда присутствует в документации, а именно в описании команды [SET SHOWPLAN_XML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187757.aspx).